# Highcharts pre-defined x-axis labels

Tags: highcharts

How do I create an exact x-axis set for my line graph that does not match my data points?
I have data points like 1345, 1434, ... 5988, but I want x-axis at pre-define increments (1000, 1500, 2000... etc)
This is specifically for presenting a dyno graph of engine power. Any help on how to set this up would be a lot of help.

Comment: You can use [`tickPositioner`](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#xAxis.tickPositioner) or [`tickPositions`](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#xAxis.tickPositions).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this [out](http://jsfiddle.net/wiltsc/yqnk19dL/).

Keyword:`xAxis.tickInterval`

API: [Link](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#xAxis.tickInterval)

Comment: Thanks, I had tried tickInterval but not in combination with the x & y values in the series data.